# getJSON API call from Jquery

Tags: jquery, json

I am trying to load a cover picture from Facebook API using Jquery and Json. Getting an error.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("button").click(function () {
            $.getJSON("https://graph.facebook.com/cocacola")
       $("#fbapi-results").attr("src", json.cover.source).appendTo("#fbapi-results");
        });
   });
```

Please see attached fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/sowljur/u8YLP/1/

UPDATE: The structure of the json file

https://graph.facebook.com/cocacola

Trying to get the source cover to load when click of the button. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$.getJSON is an async function and it needs callback http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("button").click(function () {
            $.getJSON("https://graph.facebook.com/cocacola", function (json) {
                console.log(json.cover.source);
       $("#fbapi-results").attr("src", json.cover.source).appendTo("#fbapi-results");
            })
        });
   });
```

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sajith/724Vc/

Comment: Works great! didn't know about the callback. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to know it helped!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
  $.getJSON('"https://graph.facebook.com/cocacola"jsoncall=?',
           function(data) {
              $.each(data.posts, function(key, val) {
                       // Dynamic  list creation
                      $('#Mylist').append('<li><a id="'+ val.Name +
                      '" href="' + val.proImage + '"><img  src="'
                       + val.proImage + '"   alt="'+ val.Project +
                      ' " title="" ></img></a></li>').trigger('create');

               });
     });
```

Answer (score 1):

Look into this updated fiddle. You were providing image source in div tag and was not using getJSON properly.

```
<button class="press-button">Get Facebook Coca Cola Cover</button>
<img id="fbapi-results" class="results"/>
```

and JavaScript is :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("button").click(function () {
        $.getJSON("https://graph.facebook.com/cocacola",function(root){
   $("#fbapi-results").attr("src", root.cover.source).appendTo("#fbapi-results");
    });
 });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/u8YLP/3/

Comment: I was not aware of the div tag instead of img thanks!

Comment: These things happen most of the time. Anyways its good if you got it.